# Stucked at Libtorrent

Tags: visual-studio-2017, clion, libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

I am trying to run the simplest app with libtorrent. I use Visual Studio Compiler with CLion on Windows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "libtorrent/entry.hpp"
#include "libtorrent/bencode.hpp"
#include "libtorrent/session.hpp"
#include "libtorrent/torrent_info.hpp"
#include "libtorrent/create_torrent.hpp"

using namespace libtorrent;

int main() {
    file_storage fs;
    add_files(fs, "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\temp");
    return 0;
}
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR "C:\\Users\\User\\vcpkg\\installed\\x86-windows")

add_executable(main main.cpp)
find_package(LibtorrentRasterbar CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE LibtorrentRasterbar::torrent-rasterbar)
```

But I have the next error

[image]

Comment: did you try pressing the debug-button? why is it aborting?

Comment: @Arvid if I run debug then get the next exception ```Exception 0xe06d7363 encountered at address 0x756726c2``` at the row ```movl   0x54(%esp), %ecx```

Comment: it sounds like you may need to familiarize yourself a bit more with your debugger and build environment to get helpful information out of it